# How to save movie in mjpg-streamer?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have installed mjpg-streamer on Raspbarry Pi,and it ran well.
But how to save movie in my sdcard?

I tried `mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental/mjpg_streamer -i "mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental/input_uvc.so" -o "mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental/output_http.so -w mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental/www"`,and don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any idea about `mjpg-streamer`.

But I suggest to use `Motion` library for video streaming/record movie.

By adding motion.conf file you can save it to memory card.

[This Tutorial](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/) will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried this software Motion before,but its saved movie plays so fast.For example,I recorded a 5-minute movie and saved as a .flv. But this saved movie just 5 seconds .I couldn't find a configure in motion.conf about this.         My comment may have grammar mistakes,because I'm Chinese.Please kindly understanding.

Comment: You can set frame rate in motion.conf

Answer (score 0):

you use the output_file.so plugin. so see the options run:

```
mjpg-streamer -o "output_file.so --help"
```

to get:

```
Help for output plugin..: FILE output plugin
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
The following parameters can be passed to this plugin:

[-f | --folder ]........: folder to save pictures
[-m | --mjpeg ].........: save the frames to an mjpg file
[-l | --link ]..........: link the last picture in ringbuffer as this fixed named file
[-d | --delay ].........: delay after saving pictures in ms
[-i | --input ].........: read frames from the specified input plugin
The following arguments are takes effect only if the current mode is not MJPG
[-s | --size ]..........: size of ring buffer (max number of pictures to hold)
[-e | --exceed ]........: allow ringbuffer to exceed limit by this amount
[-c | --command ].......: execute command after saving picture
```

use the -m to save the stream to a motion jpg file. if you don't want to save all input frames use the -d to delay between saved frames